# How does recursion work in Haskell? - Example merge function

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

if we look at the funtion definition of merge

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x <= y    = x:merge xs (y:ys)
                    | otherwise = y:merge (x:xs) ys
```

With the input [2,3] [4,1]

the first step looks like this

`2<=4 => 2:merge [3] (1:[4])`

Here my question lies: The first head element of the second list was 4 but since 2<=4 nothing was done with 4 so the 4 has to be still in the second list but the 4 needs to be the last element in the list now so 3 can be compared to the 1. I wonder how the compiler changes the second list: At first 4 was the head element but since it makes none sense to compare the 3 to the 4 again the indices has to be switched.

So the compiler just put the head element to the end of the list after the first comparison? Or what does the compiler do here?

Answer (score 4):

> I wonder how the compiler changes the second list.

It does not. If we call `merge [2,3] [4,1]` then the clause you describe will fire, with: `x = 2`, `y = 4`, `xs = [3]` and `ys = [1]`. It will indeed check that `2 <= 4`, which holds, and then call merge with:

```
x : merge xs (y:ys)
```

so that means that if we use the variables we just assigned, we get:

```
2 : merge [3] (4:[1])
```

or less verbose:

```
2 : merge [3] [4,1]
```

> I wonder how the compiler changes the second list: At first 4 was the head element but since it makes none sense to compare the 3 to the 4 again the indices has to be switched.

Such `merge` function often has a *precondition* that the two lists it aims to merge, are sorted *individually* already. So normally `merge [2,3] [4,1]` will not be called with an algorithm like *MergeSort*, the two lists are first sorted, and then it is thus called with `merge [2,3] [1,4]`.

Answer (score 3):

`3` *isn't* compared to `1` until it has been compared to `4` as well; `merge` preserves the relative order of each value within a single list.

The recursion proceeds as follows:

```
merge [2,3] [4,1] == 2 : merge [3] [4,1]  -- 2 < 4
                  == 2 : 3 : merge [] [4, 1] -- 3 < 4
                  == 2 : 3 : [4, 1] -- assuming merge [] ys == ys
```

---

Don't confuse `merge` with `mergeSort`, which *uses* `merge` as a subroutine.

```
mergeSort [] = []
mergeSort xs = merge (mergeSort first) (mergeSort second)
   where (first, second) = split xs
         split xs = ... -- some function to split a list roughly in half
```

The order-preserving behavior of `merge` is what makes `mergeSort` a [stable sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).